# simplexml_load_string doesn't accept single XML tags

Tags: php, xml

I have problem with `PHP` `simplexml_load_string()` function. I'm using external API which as a response returns `XML` string, as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<audience>
  <member>
    <first_name>Adam</first_name>
    <last_name/>
    <lists>
      <list>hihi</list>
    </lists>
  </member>
</audience>
```

And the when i use `simplexml_load_string($xmlString)` i recieve `false` instead of object.
Is there any way for `simplexml_load_string()` function accepting single tags? In this case I would like to get `last_name` as empty node.

Comment: Here is a `<` missing from the `</list>`. https://3v4l.org/ZEbMn

Comment: Yeah, it's not the case. I deleted too much to post it here. My bad.

Comment: Now that you've edited the XML to be valid, it's not really clear what problem you're having. What do you mean by getting it "as empty node"? If it doesn't have any content or attributes, what exactly do you want to get?

Comment: I wanted to use something like @ThW, but instead of plain `XML` string i wanted to use variable with same `XML`

Comment: You get a xml-object from the string with $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

Answer (score 0):

Below code works just fine. Shows `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) { }` for the last line. See [this 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/JP7H4).

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$xml = <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<audience>
  <member>
    <first_name>Adam</first_name>
    <last_name/>
    <lists>
      <list>hihi</list>
    </lists>
  </member>
</audience>
EOT;

if (($o = simplexml_load_string($xml)) === FALSE)
{
        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error)
                echo "{$error->message}<br>\n";

        exit;
}
var_dump($o->member->last_name);
```